# SQL Query Mathematic operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, integer-division

I Exec below code in SQL Server Management Studio

```
SELECT       CAST (9/100 AS DECIMAL(8,3))
```

this should return 0.090 but Return 0.000 .

Who can tell what the problem is and why it gives me this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that the `9/100` ratio is computed using integer division *before* you make the cast to decimal.  By the time that cast happens, it is already too late and you've lost the decimal component.  Simply I would just do:

```sql
SELECT 9 / 100.0;  -- 0.090000
```

So long as the numerator or denominator be a decimal, the quotient will also carry the decimal result.